# Can i set https.protocols in Tomcat catalina.properties?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, pci-compliance

We are using Tomcat 7.0.41 with Java 1.7.x.  For PCI compliance reasons, I want to disable TLS 1.0.  So my question is can i set the below values in catalina.properties? 
  **https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2**
My concern is mainly for my web app that makes outbound service calls to an external vendor via https. In this case my webapp is a java client. 
In addition, my webapp also serves pages to a browser and I plan to control that TLS within my server.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a service that makes calls out, then this doesn't really have anything to do with Tomcat. In Tomcat, you can simply configure `sslEnabledProtocols` on your `<Connector>` to restrict/enable arbitrary protocols.

For configuring available protocols for outgoing connections, it *would be best* if you could interact with the client library you are using (e.g. `httpclient`, etc.) to set the protocol, but if you want to do it at the JVM level, you will in fact want to set the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` to include `TLSv1` (for Java 8+) or `https.protocols` as you have in our question.

Tomcat does not allow you to set arbitrary system properties in `catalina.properties`. You'll have to set them elsewhere, such as in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.(sh|bat)` or in whatever service-launching facility you use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I will likely use **setenv.sh** for setting -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2.  I found that setenv.sh is not present by default, so i have to create it (in Tomcat 7 at least.) I am doing more analysis on all settings.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you will have to create `setenv.sh` yourself. Don't be shy! Also remember that `setenv.sh` is not run is you launch Tomcat using `jsvc` or possibly a service-launcher provided by your OS's package manager.